# Subdividing causes details to "lift" off object

Tags: mesh

Still learning my way around Blender, so I apologize for the newbie question.

This is the piece I am trying to work with before applying the subdivision modifier.
[![Unaltered mesh][1]][1]

Here I have altered the mesh a bit by dividing some faces and using extrude region to add some detail. I go and use the subdivide modifier. I want sharp creases on the extruded area, so I crease the areas to 1. Once I do that the corners lift off the base mesh.

[image]

How do I fix this? Is there a better way (different method) to use to add the detail?

Example Blender file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2501

Answer (score 1):

You can add detail using [creases](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#edge-crease), [loop cuts](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop_subdivide.html#loop-cut-and-slide) and [extrusion](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/extrude.html#extrude-region) without a problem.

The subdivision surface modifier does not work (well) with triangular faces or ngons. It works best with quads (faces with four vertices).

Subdiving can cause triangles to appear, be aware that you may have to alter your geometry.

Try joining the triangular faces to merge into quads by selecting all <kbd>A</kbd> and pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. The [triangles to quads](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html?highlight=join%20triangles#triangles-to-quads) operation can also be found under ***Mesh > Faces > Tris to Quad***.

Or do the [convex hull](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#convex-hull) operation. In edit mode under ***Mesh > Vertices > Convex Hull***.

1. In your case there are two bad edge loop. Select them with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>. Then delete them with <kbd>X</kbd> > Edges.
2. Then select all <kbd>A</kbd>and press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to convert tris to quads.

[image]

3. Now you can crease the edge loops.

[image]

4. The topology still has a problematic edge, delete the two edges as shown in the following image. Subdivide the center edge, with <kbd>W</kbd> > <kbd>S</kbd>. Then fill in the missing four faces with <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

The vertical edge crease will work now. Read up on proper **topology** and **edge loop flow**.

Comment: Tried all the above options and still no dice, even though the functions worked on the object, when subdividing, detail still lifts off the parent object. Thanks for the tips, though!

Comment: You can upload your .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. This makes trouble shooting easier for other.

Comment: Done! The mesh is subdivided and I creased one corner of the detail to show where lift is occurring.
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2501/

Comment: Edit your question to include your blender file. I updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Almost there, but I'm having the same issue with the point at the bottom. I've subdivided some of the faces at the bottom and made them quads, and this helps, but still not 100%, what am I missing?